# Geotools 8.4 CRS.decode invalid(?) reference to HTTP_URI_OGC

Tags: java, geotools

I'm trying to do a simple CRS.decode to lookup a CoordinateReference system:

E.g. CoordinateReferenceSystem target_crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

However this fails with a reference to the Citations.HTTP_URI_OGC field, and an invalid field error. According to the documentation this field is introduced in v9?

Anyone else experienced this, or got an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Regards

Rune Sørensen

Comment: Are you sure you have included all correct GeoTools dependencies? For example [epsg-hsql](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CA%2bnxMTswggtHh3%2be1_GGT2BmOBs3eM4QNdFWm2KJszVQ09ECUA@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=geotools-gt2-users)? If that doesn't solve the problem please supply more information.

Comment: I think you need gt-metadata for org.geotools.metadata.iso.citation.*; What does maven think?